# Complex Analysis D shaped contour

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

Hi there. I am stuck on c. I proved (b) using Rouches theorem.

To calculate the integral in c, I was not sure what to do. I am guessing you use the result in (b) somehow, but I thought that Rouche's theorem only tells you about the number of zeroes and not what they are, so I am not sure how (b) helps me to solve c

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: the numerator is the derivative of the denominator. So count the poles and zeros inside the contour and then apply the argument principle.

A second hint, if you have trouble counting the poles: $z^4+z+4$ has real coefficients, what does this say about its roots?

Comment: Ahh thanks! For $4z^{3}+1$ are there two roots in the contour and $z^{4}+z+4$ are there two as well? Does that make the integral 0?

Comment: That's correct. :)

Comment: @ArchieJudd I think I made an error. If you look carefully, $-(4^{-1/3})$ (the real root of $4z^3+1$) is on the contour, not inside the contour. This means you can't directly apply the argument principle. Instead you have to do something else to deal with that point, and I'm not quite sure what that should be. My first instinct is to deform the contour with a semicircle of radius $\varepsilon$, such that the contour contains $-(4^{-1/3})$, then send $\varepsilon \to 0$. Try this, perhaps?

Comment: @ArchieJudd Now I see my mistake. I just misremembered the argument principle. All that matters are the zeros and poles of the *denominator*. $z^4+z+4$ has two zeros and no poles in the contour, so the argument principle says the integral is $4 \pi i$. The fact that $4z^3+1$ has zeros in/on the contour is irrelevant. My apologies, I really should not try to do math before coffee.

Comment: ah right!! i.e. only the poles/zeroes of $f(z)$ matter and not of $f'(z)$. Thanks for all the help!